# Fabric Answers Crashes on ANSRotateCrashMetadataOperation

Tags: google-fabric

Fabrics Answers seems to be crashing. I found the same crash log on the iOS Realm [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5471) on Github.

```
Crashed: io.answers.EventQueue :: NSOperation 0x17405fbc0 (QOS: BACKGROUND)
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x101084da0 _stdlib_destroyTLS + 294720
...
11 XXXXX                          0x1001f2c4c -[ANSRotateCrashMetadataOperation initWithCrashMetadataURL:currentMetadata:] (ANSRotateCrashMetadataOperation.m:28)
12 XXXXX                          0x1001ffdf8 -[ANSAnswersController replacePreviousExecutionMetadataWithCurrentMetadata:inRootDirectory:] (ANSAnswersController.m:273)
13 XXXXX                          0x1001fecb8 __56-[ANSAnswersController initWithBetaToken:rootDirectory:]_block_invoke (ANSAnswersController.m:103)
...
```

Comment: Thanks. Todd from Fabric. Please let me know what versions of our SDKs you are using. Also, are you building a native iOS app or using Realm like the link?

Comment: Hi @ToddBurner, The Fabric version is 1.7.6 and I am building a plain native iOS app without Realm.